# How can I speed up my RSS feed Android App?

Tags: java, performance, parsing, android, rss

I have a problem with parsing RSS from a PHP page because the app is too slow.

This is my parsing code:

```
public void getdataparse(String url) {

    Log.d("Do in Background","Start Call Void");

    String dbtitle = "";
    String dbDesc = "";
    String dbimgicon = "";
    String dbimg = "";
    String dblink = "";
    String dbpubdate = "";
    String dborderStg = "";
    String dbsourcename = "";
    String dbimagecheck = "";
    int dbfff = 0;


        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new URL(url).openStream());

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {


                dbtitle = "";
                dbDesc = "";
                dbimgicon = "";
                dbimg = "";
                dblink = "";
                dbpubdate = "";
                dborderStg = "";
                dbsourcename = "";
                dbimagecheck = "";
                dbfff = 0;
                Datemx = 0;
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    dbtitle = getTagValue("title", eElement);

                    dbDesc = getTagValue("description", eElement);

                    String[] timeformated = new String[2];

                    timeformated = gettime(getTagValue("pubdate", eElement));

                    dbpubdate = timeformated[0];

                    dborderStg = timeformated[1];

                    Log.d("pubDate = ", "" + dbpubdate + "OrderStg = " + dborderStg);

                    dblink = getTagValue("link", eElement);


                    dbimgicon = getTagValue("sicon", eElement);

                    dbimg = "http://s14.postimg.org/cs10sq11d/whitemega.png";

                    dbsourcename = getTagValue("sname", eElement);

                    dbimagecheck = "";

                    dbfff = Datemx;

                    handler = new DataHandler(getBaseContext());
                    handler.open();
                    long id = handler.insertrssfeedData(dbtitle, dbDesc, dbimg, dbimgicon, dblink, dbpubdate, dbfff, dbsourcename , dbimagecheck);
                    handler.close();

                    Log.d("Add New Recorde","Record = " + temp + "/n Title = " + dbtitle);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[The PHP page URL](http://www.megane.ws/myrss/newsreader.php)

[The PHP code](http://www.megane.ws/myrss/newsreader.txt)

Comment: If you want a review of your PHP code, you should ask a new question about that and include that code in the post itself.

Comment: i think the php code is the problem

Answer (score 5):

none of those Variables need to be set to `""` inside the for loop, they have already been set.

---

This can be set early and outside of the if block and the for loop:

```
 dbimg = "http://s14.postimg.org/cs10sq11d/whitemega.png";
```

Otherwise it is a Magic string that you will have to search for later.

---

The `id` isn't doing anything here, I don't think that you need it at all, you should be able to call the code like this

```
handler.insertrssfeedData(dbtitle, dbDesc, dbimg, dbimgicon, dblink, dbpubdate, dbfff, dbsourcename , dbimagecheck);
```

otherwise you are creating this variable and assigning a lot of data to it and never using it every time you go through the loop.

Comment: I am very grateful for your response and I will be following these tips and thank you

Comment: @user3680042 you are welcome.  I look forward to seeing more of your code in the future

Answer (score 5):

## Performance

I don't see any performance bottlenecks unfortunately.

## Style and stuff

You're using a lot of empty lines, I would reduce the number of empty lines you have. You also use way too much lowercase in your variable names. (Although `Datemx` doesn't start with a small character, which it should).

It is hard to read text that is only written in lowercase and not space-separated, by using someBigCharactersHereAndThere it can be read more easily.

Some simple naming changes:

- timeformated --> timeFormatted
- dbimg --> dbImage
- dbimagecheck --> dbImageCheck

## Another Library

If you would use [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) and it's XML-parsing capabilities, you would reduce a lot of your code. Jackson has the ability to parse XML and provide a Java object for it - if you first manage to create a class that has correct structure and annotations for the data with which Jackson should create it. I am not sure if using Jackson will make your code any faster or not, however.

The `handler.insertrssfeedData` method, or rather, `handler.insertRssFeedData` which you might want to rename it to, has a lot of parameters. By using the Jackson library, you will be able to reduce the number of parameters to only one.

## Logging

The first parameter to `Log.d` should be a TAG that is used to categorize logging messages. Preferably, your entire application should use the same tag.

```
private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

Log.d(TAG, message);
```

This allows it to be filtered with adb's `logcat` command.

What good will calling `e.printStackTrace();` do? It won't tell the user anything at runtime. Consider creating a dialog window that says what went wrong instead of simply printing the stack trace.

Comment: I am very grateful for your response and I will be following these tips and thank you